# Discovering specific phone model in JS

Tags: javascript, mobile, user-agent, browser-detection

I am aware that User Agent sniffing is not a fool-proof approach due to the plethora of devices that are getting released on a day-to-day basis, however I need a way to pick up the precise phone model that a user is accessing my site with in order to direct him/her to the appropriate help area/documentation.

Tools such as http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ allow you to detect the mobile device, browser, os etc but is there anything that can pick up the specific phone model you are using (using Javascript)? E.g iPhone **4s**

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

this is the best i've found so far http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect, but you need php